# C# .net deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialize JSON in my object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class FormData
{
    public string audience { get; set; }
    public Calendar[] calendar { get; set; }

    public FormData()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public class Calendar
    {
        public Quarter quarter { get; set; }
    }

    public class Quarter
    {
        public int qtrNumber { get; set; }
        public string qtrString { get; set; }
        public int[] qtrTools { get; set; }
        public int qtrYear { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my handler:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ToolHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


public class ToolHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        try
        {
            string strJson = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

            //deserialize the object
            FormData formData = serializer.Deserialize<FormData>(strJson);
            if (formData != null)
            {
                Response.Write("Success!!");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("No Data");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error :" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "audience": "8",
    "calendar": [
        {
            "qtrNumber": 1,
            "qtrYear": 2016,
            "qtrString": "1st Quarter",
            "qtrTools": [
                "3",
                "4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "qtrNumber": 2,
            "qtrYear": 2016,
            "qtrString": "2nd Quarter",
            "qtrTools": []
        },
        {
            "qtrNumber": 3,
            "qtrYear": 2016,
            "qtrString": "3rd Quarter",
            "qtrTools": []
        },
        {
            "qtrNumber": 4,
            "qtrYear": 2016,
            "qtrString": "4th Quarter",
            "qtrTools": []
        }
    ]
}
```

What I see after the execution of this line:

```
FormData formData = serializer.Deserialize<FormData>(strJson);
```

formData object has proper audience and calendar with the array of 4 elements, but all calendar[].quarter objects are null. Please help ))

Comment: Look at your json... where's `quarter: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Calendar` class has no nested `Quarter` property in the JSON. You could "unnest" the nested properties, and everything should work fine:

```
public class FormData
{
    public string audience { get; set; }
    public Calendar[] calendar { get; set; }

    public FormData()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public class Calendar
    {
        public int qtrNumber { get; set; }
        public string qtrString { get; set; }
        public int[] qtrTools { get; set; }
        public int qtrYear { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mq1wyP

Comment: thanks it makes sense now. I am somewhat a newbie to c#.

Answer (score 0):

None of the "qtr" properties are on `calendar`, they are  on `Quarter`. Your JSON would have to be:

```
{
    "audience": "8",
    "calendar": [ {"Quarter" :
        {
            "qtrNumber": 1,
            "qtrYear": 2016,
            "qtrString": "1st Quarter",
            "qtrTools": [
                "3",
                "4"
            ]
        }},
        {"Quarter" : { 
            "qtrNumber": 2,
            "qtrYear": 2016,
            "qtrString": "2nd Quarter",
            "qtrTools": []
        }},
        etc...
    ]
}
```